# Error regarding inlineeval in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, methods, matrix, inline

As part of a group project we have a system of 2 non linear differential equations and we have to draw the S=S(t) , I=I(t) graphic using the midpoint method.

And I'm getting the following error when trying to insert the matrix with the corresponding differential equations:

"Error in inline expression ==> matrix([[-(I*S)/1000], [(I*S)/1000 - (3*I)/10]])
 Undefined function 'matrix' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in inline/subsref (line 23)
    INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);"

The code I have done is the following:

```
syms I S
u=[S;I];
F=[-0.001*S*I;0.001*S*I-0.3*I];
F1=inline(char(F),'I','S');
h=100; %Valores aleatórios
T=100000;
ni=(T/h);
u0=[799;1];
f=zeros(1,2);
k=zeros(1,2);
i=1;

while i<=ni
f(1)=F1(u0(1));  
f(2)=F1(u0(2));
dx=h*f;
k(1)=F1((u0(1)+h*(1/2)),(u0(2)+h*(1/2)));  
k(2)=F1((u0(1)+h*(1/2)),(u0(2)+h*(1/2)));
u1=u0+h*k;
disp('i:'),disp(i)
disp('u= '),disp(u1)
u0=u1;
i=i+1;
end
```

I'm new to this so the algorithm it's very likely to be wrong but if someone could help me with that error I'd apreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: `F1` is an inline function that will call function `matrix`. Is function `matrix` visible to Matlab, that is, is it in the local folder of your code or in the path?

Comment: Using "which matrix" it says its not found, but I didn't create any matrix function

Comment: Hum, after some more research, I reckon my previous comment was a bit misleading. I don't really know much about `sym` but the error you are getting should be related to [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25281-error-in-inline-expression-matrix). I think you should try going from there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem that specifically creates the error is that you are putting two symbolic functions into a matrix and then calling `char` (which outputs `matrix([[-(IS)/1000], [(IS)/1000 - (3*I)/10]])` rather than converting nicely to string).

The secondary problem is that you are trying to pass two functions simultaneously to `inline`.  `inline` creates a single function from a string (and using anonymous functions instead of `inline` is preferred anyway).  You cannot put multiple functions in it.

You don't need `sym` here. In fact, avoid it (more trouble than it's worth) if you don't need to manipulate the equations at all.  A common method is to create a cell array:

```
F{1} = @(I,S) -0.001*S*I; 
F{2} = @(I,S) 0.001*S*I-0.3*I;
```

You can then pass in `I` and `S` as so:

```
F{1}(500,500)
```

Note that both your functions include both `I` and `S`, so they are always necessary. Reconsider what you were expecting when passing only one variable like this: `f(1)=F1(u0(1));`, because that will also give an error.

Comment: Yes I noticed that it wouldn't pass two functioncs simultaneously to inline so I deciced to pass 1 by 1 and I fixed that f(1)=F1(u0(1)) too. It's already working, just need to fix the algorithm of the midpoint method itself. Thank you very much for your answer!